# How to create html css js editor with colored tags like in w3schools.com

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here i have a code which I found on the internet but there some issues that I want to modify.

I found html, css, js text editor but I want key words to be colored like in *w3schools.com*. And also I want to run the code manually not live.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/qd9sp3a5/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web Editor</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="tag">HTML (Body)</div>
                    <div id="html" class="content" contenteditable></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="tag">CSS</div>
                    <div id="css" class="content" contenteditable></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="tag">JavaScript</div>
                    <div id="js" class="content" contenteditable></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="tag">Output</div>
                    <iframe id="output"></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    var html=document.getElementById("html"),
        css=document.getElementById("css"),
        js=document.getElementById("js"),
        output=document.getElementById("output"),
        working=false,
        fill=function(){
            if(working){
                return false;
            }
            working=true;
            var document=output.contentDocument,
                style=document.createElement("style"),
                script=document.createElement("script");
            document.body.innerHTML=html.textContent;
            style.innerHTML=css.textContent.replace(/\s/g,"");
            script.innerHTML=js.textContent;
            document.body.appendChild(style);
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            working=false;
        };
    html.onkeyup=fill;
    css.onkeyup=fill;
    js.onkeyup=fill;
}
</script>
<style>
html,body,table,div.content,iframe{
    border:0;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
td{
    border:2px solid black;
    height:50%;
    padding:25px 5px 5px 5px;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:50%;
}
div.tag{
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
}
</style>
```

Here i have a code which I found on the internet but there some issues that I want to modify.

I found html, css, js text editor but I want key words to be colored like in *w3schools.com*. And also I want to run the code manually not live.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/qd9sp3a5/

Answer (score 0):

Key words as in the tags? if so, all you need to do is:

```
div.tag{
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    top:5px; 
    color: 'your color'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by keywords he means like `<head></head>` `<div></div>` or really anything that is a tag header or footer for css,html,js etc not the pieces they has in the code already i’ve been searching for this answer for a while and still cant find a direct answer that actually works